# How can I FindPython.cmake that was built from source in develop mode?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, build, dependencies

I have been trying to build a Python extension and to debug some memory related problems I have built Python from source in develop mode [using](https://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging/valgrind.html#building-python-for-valgrind-label):

```
git clone https://github.com/python/cpython.git
cd cpython
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/install-python-with-valgrind-options --enable-framework --with-pydebug --without-pymalloc --with-valgrind
sudo make frameworkinstall
```

Now I want to link the newly built Python using the standard CMake `FindPython.cmake`:

```
...
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
```

To configure the cmake project I am using

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DPython_ROOT_DIR=/home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options ..
```

Which finds the following:

```
    Python_ROOT_DIR                            /home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options
    Python_FOUND                               FALSE
    Python_Interpreter_FOUND                   FALSE
    Python_EXECUTABLE                          _Python_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
    Python_INTERPRETER_ID                      Python
    IronPython                                 
    Python_STDLIB                              /home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options/lib/python3.11
    Python_STDARCH                             /home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options/lib/python3.11
    Python_SITELIB                             /home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options/lib/python3.11/site-packages
    Python_SITEARCH                            /home/ciaran/cpython/build-valgrind/install-python-with-valgrind-options/lib/python3.11/site-packages
    Python_SOABI                               
    Python_Compiler_FOUND                      FALSE
    Python_COMPILER                            
    Python_COMPILER_ID                         
    Python_DOTNET_LAUNCHER                     
    Python_Development_FOUND                   FALSE
    Python_Development                         
    Module_FOUND                               
    Python_Development                         
    Embed_FOUND                                
    Python_INCLUDE_DIRS                        
    Python_LINK_OPTIONS                        
    Python_LIBRARY                             
    Python_LIBRARIES                           Python_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
    Python_LIBRARY_DIRS                        
    Python_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DIRS                
    Python_VERSION                             
    Python_VERSION_MAJOR                       
    Python_VERSION_MINOR                       
    Python_VERSION_PATCH                       
    Python_PyPy_VERSION                        
    Python_NumPy_FOUND                         FALSE
    Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS                  _Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
    Python_NumPy_VERSION
```

I also have not been able to provide the missing ones manually with `-D` syntax since the `x_FOUND` variables remain `FALSE` regardless of whether they are `-D`'d - this means a project configured to use the `x_FOUND` variables is incorrectly configured.

I'm using ubuntu-18.04 on WSL with gcc version 10.3.0 and cmake version 3.21.1. Do you have any advice on how to find python built from source using `FindPython.cmake`?

Comment: your prefix is `install-python-with-valgrind` but you are setting `Python_ROOT_DIR` to `install-python-with-valgrind-options`?

Comment: Ah, no this is a typo in the question - apologies... and as you can see, FindPython has located *some* of the variables: `Python_STDLIB` for instance.

Comment: have you installed NumPy?

Comment: Yes, I used `./bin/pip3 install numpy` from `Python_ROOT_DIR`